# Using die() to return array?

Tags: php

Assume the following code...

```
function helper_function($arg){
   if($arg === NULL){
      // I want this to act like die();
      return ["error" => "the variable is null"];
   }else{
      return ["success!" => $arg];
   }
}

// now, we use our helper function
$another_value = "test";

function my_function($another_value){
   helper_function(NULL);
   helper_function($another_value);
}
```

now the problem here is that I use `helper_function` around 10+ times in my code, so I can't just be checking for **if an error exists** in the output of that function every time I call it.

**TLDR:** `my_function()` should return the error.

Please let me know if this is unclear. Very big thanks

Comment: return the error where? after returning something, the function execution stops, and you can not still kill the process. if you want to terminate the process, either kill it outright in the function, or if you need to do something else with the error, before terminating the program, you must either do it inside the function, or terminate the execution outside it. if you want to kill the process, INSTEAD of returning an error, you can use `exit` for that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: @AdamBaranyai im calling that function from another file, what I do is that I simply execute `my_function("my value")`. Now, I dont want to check for if `helper_function()` returned an error everytime I call it, `helper_function()` should instead halt that class's execution and return an array, so no further checks are sent over. Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by halting the class execution? should it outright kill the whole php script, or just stop the logic that should be executed after the function call?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai `my_function()` should return the error.

Comment: If you want script execution to be halted/killed, throwing an exception without catching it can be one way. However, such methods are not recommended. You will need to elaborate more for a better flow of error messages across the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand correctly what you want, but based on the comments you provided, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function helper_function($arg){
   if($arg === NULL) throw new Exception('the variable is null');
   else{
      return ["success!" => $arg];
   }
}

function my_function($another_value) {
    helper_function($another_value); // first call
    helper_function(null); // second call
    helper_function($another_value); // third call
}

try {
    my_function('test');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    /** one of the helper functions encountered an error do something to recover from this error **/
}
```

If `helper_function` throws an exception, you can catch that exception in an outer function also, thus you don't have to check after every `helper_function` for an error. This way, if `my_function` encounters an error, it will be reported back to you in the `catch` block of the code.

You can read more about `Exceptions` here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

If `helper_function` can raise different kind of errors, and you want to know the exact error raised, you can modify the functions in the following way:

```
function helper_function($arg) {
   if ($arg === NULL) throw new Exception('null value received', 100);
   else if ($arg === false) throw new Exception('false value received', 200);
   else return ["success!" => $arg];
}

try {
    my_function($another_value);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() === 100) {
       // a null value was received somewhere, do something about it
    } else if ($e->getMessage() === 'false value received') {
       // a false value was received somewhere, do something about it
    }
}
```

Basically, you can retrieve the exception message and/or code from the caught exception, thus you can raise different kind of errors, and handle those errors in a way you see fit.

Comment: can I use `throw new Exception(["error" => "some error here"]);`?

Comment: no, with the basic exception, you can not. You can add however a message or a code, to the thrown exception, and both can be retrieved after catching it, or you can create your own custom exception that acceps additional parameters in a structure defined by you. I will edit the answer a bit in a moment.

Comment: ynoe what this will do, I only have to handle the error once and thats what I wanted, I thank you very much

Comment: @lolc You can json_encode() it while throwing and decode it while catching.